# Node.js API find a MongoDB Document by passing ObjectID

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The following GET ALL route is working. The second route below, I am trying to retrieve a single Employee document by ObjectId.  This is not working.  Please help. My Employee model is at the bottom.

```
// Get all Employees
    router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const employees = await Employee.find();
        res.json(employees);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
    }
});


// Get Single Employee by ObjectId
router.get("/:id", (req, res) => {
    try {
        const employees = await Employee.find(id)
        res.json(employees);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
    }
});

const employeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
    },
        fname: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
    },
    lname: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use `findById(id)` or `find({_id: id})`

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find